# How to sets this input-box to center

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS now and trying to imitate Youtube's homepage.

But I don't know how to set this input in the middle of this .input-box

[image: Page's photo]

Please help me to solve this problem.
I tried to search it on Google, but the solution will change the margin and i don't know how.
Here is my code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input_box">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.input_box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 519px;
    height: 26px;
}

.input_box>input {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1px 0 1px 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    outline: none;

    font-family: inherit;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    background-color: #11274c;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

I set the background color this way to make it easier for me to tell

Comment: Please explain the red areas in the image.  I don't see anything in your code that would produce that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
.input_box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You may add the above style to your input box's outer div so that it will behave as a flexbox container vertically aligning its items.

To align items horizontally you can add `justify-content: center;`.

Comment: This did not appear to fix the problem when I tried it.  Please add a demo snippet.

Comment: Thank you!!! That really works, this solution changes it in a proper way! Thx, and have a good day!

Comment: if it's correct answer then please mark it as answer and upvote so the question will  marked as an answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
.input_box {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 519px;
 height: 26px;

 margin: 0 auto;
 float : none;}
```